# how to insert multiple data into a single column into the database

Tags: laravel

Am learning laravel and I encountered a problem saving data into my database from my form.

My instance

when a user tries to make a multiple purchase of products ie.when a user purchases more than one product,i wanted to save the names of products that belongs to the purchase  user made into my 'PURCHASES' table having an 'ID' of '1'.
Names of product to be save;

1.productA
2.productB
3.productC

Codes

FORM IN MY VIEW

```
<input type='hidden'                     name='product_name'
 @foreach($order as $order)
  value='{{$order->product_name}}'
  @endforeach >
```

MY purchase CONTROLLER

Saving the names;

```
  $purchase = new Purchase;

  $purchase->product_name   = $posted['product_name'];

  $purchase->save();
```

When i initiate the function i get an error exception reading 'Trying to get property of non-object' from my view from the line;

```
@foreach($order as $order)
value='{{$order-         >product_name}}'
 @endforeach >
```

How do i go about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of strange things in your code unless I'm reading it wrong, but most likely when you're seeing that error in a view it's because you didn't pass that data into the view. Take this example:

Controller

```
public function showProducts() {

    // assuming $order_array is a set of product IDs that is part of an order
    $orders = array('products' => Products::whereIn('id', $order_array);
    return View::make('your/view' compact('orders'));

}
```

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do but passing the object array 'orders' to the view allows you to then call your line:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
   code here
@endforeach
```